# Network Cluster Builder Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

I am developing a client server network using python. I want a network that has multiple clients connected to a single server and that server will acts as client and this client is connected to multiple servers. How can I do it. I have written some function for connection and sending data
Here is the code:

```
import socket

def streamServerConnect(tcpIP,tcpPort):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((tcpIP, tcpPort))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    return conn, addr

def streamClientConnect(tcpIP,tcpPort):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((tcpIP, tcpPort))
    return s

def streamServerReceive(conn,bufferSize):
    while 1:
        data=conn.recv(bufferSize)
        if not data: break
        bufferQueue.append(data.decode())
        conn.send(data)
    conn.close()
    return bufferQueue

def streamClientSend(socket,bufferSize,message):
    socket.send(message.encode())
    data=socket.recv(bufferSize)
    socket.close()
    return data
```

I am not getting how should I design my server to accept connection and receive data simultaneously from multiple clients and make server as a client simultaneously and connect to multiple servers. Can Anyone please help me?. I want a network like this[image: flowGraph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should'nt  do this ,
what you wont  to implement is load balancing

you should use [ha proxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
- client  post request ->  haproxy  handle it ->
redirect to the server
server ->  send response via haproxy to the client.